# How to display tab widget in the middle of layout?

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am trying to display tab widget in the middle of layout as shown below.

[image]

I have few text views, progress bar etc. before tab widget. 
Is this possible to implement in android?
If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Let's say you have a vertical `LinearLayout` as your main layout.  You would have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- put your top widgets/progress bars here
         their height needs to be fixed or wrap_content -->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pagertabstrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```